# Who is SABDFL? What does he do?

Tags: community

what is the meaning of SABDFL?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

SABDFL stands for Self Appointed Benevolent Dictator For Life, and is the nickname and IRC nick of Mark Shuttleworth, the guy who started the Ubuntu project.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SABDFL

Answer (score 3):

Self-Appointed Benevolent Dictator for Life

[Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benevolent_dictator_for_life)

> Benevolent Dictator For Life or BDFL is a title given to a small
>   number of open source software development leaders.